# Why positive lookahead is working but negative lookahead doesn't?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

First of all, regex needs to be working for both the python and PCRE(PHP). I'm trying to ignore if a regex pattern is followed by the letter 'x' to distinguish dimensions from strings like "number/number" in the given example below:

```
dummy word 222/2334; Ø14 x Ø6,33/523,23 x 2311 mm
```

From here, I'm trying to extract `222/2334` but not the `6,33/523,23` since that part is actually part of dimensions. So far I came up with this regex

```
((\d*(?:,?\.?)\d*(?:,?\.?))\s?\/\s?(\d*(?:,?\.?)\d*(?:,?\.?)))(?=\s?x)
```

which can extract what I don't want it to extract and it looks like [this](https://regex101.com/r/Onyzmy/1/). If I change the positive lookahead to negative it captures both of them except the last '3' from `6,33/523,23`. It looks like [this](https://regex101.com/r/6grXFf/2). How can I only capture `222/2334`? What am I doing wrong here?

Desired output:

```
222/2334
```

What I got

```
222/2334 6,33/523,2
```

Comment: I mean... It's not pretty but works in both languages: `(?!\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?\s?\/\s?\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?(?=\s?x))(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)\s?\/\s?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)`. Alternatively, you could use `(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?+)\s?\/\s?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?+)(?!\s?x)` and the `regex` module in python to support possessive quantifiers

Comment: Wow... that fast? Could you explain it a little bit? @ctwheels

Comment: The last digit doesn't match the regexp `\s?x`, so the negative lookahead is satisfied when it matches the number leading up to that digit.

Comment: Per your exact example, `(^| )(\d+)\/(\d+)($|;)` would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this simplified regex with negative lookahead:

```
((\d*(?:,?\.?)\d*(?:,?\.?))\s?\/\s?(\d*(?:,?\.?)\d*(?:,?\.?)))\b(?![.,]?\d|\s?x)
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6grXFf/4)

- It is important to use a word boundary in the end to avoid matching partial numbers (the reason of your regex matching till a digit before)
- Also include `[.,]?\d` in negative lookahead condition so that match doesn't end at position before last comma.

---

This shorter (and more efficient) regex may also work for OP:

```
(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)\s*\/\s*(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)\b(?![.,]?\d|\s?x)
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/6grXFf/6)

Comment: Shorter regex has some issues with floats. It can't match floats like 2222,232/233,4

Comment: It will match `2222,232/233,4` as well. I had a typo in my regex and missed `+` after `\d`. It should be `(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)\s*\/\s*(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*)\b(?![.,]?\d|\s?x)`

Comment: Yes, it is working now. Thank you. One last question (I know this is asking too much). I'm trying to make this regex pattern optional. I am adding another pattern to capture the dimension next to those parts. But for some reason, it is not becoming optional and instead it is becoming 'necessary' like pattern I mean, it is not capturing dimensions if your regex doesn't match. To make it optional I am putting your regex in between `()` and adding `.*?` next to it.

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me. I suggest you please post a new question with examples so that I can understand it better and try to provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are two *easy* options.

The first option is ugly and long, but basically negates a positive match on the string that is followed by `x`, then matches the patterns without it.

`(?!PATTERN(?=x))PATTERN`

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/vBmeou/2)

```
(?!\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?\s?\/\s?\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?(?=\s?x))(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)\s?\/\s?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)
```

The second option uses possessive quantifiers, but you'll have to use the `regex` module instead of `re` in python.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/vBmeou/1)

```
(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?+)\s?\/\s?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?+)(?!\s?x)
```

---

Additionally, I changed your subpattern to `\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?`. This will match one or more digits, then optionally match `.` or `,` followed by one or more digits.

Comment: Second regex throwing an error on regex101 if flavor is set to python but the first one works on both PHP and python.

Comment: @MehmedB Yes, that's why I specified that you'd have to use the [Pypi `regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) instead of `re`

Comment: Now I get it. I will test it tomorrow. This looks promising.

Comment: Yours truly has given an almost perfect answer but @anubhava 's answer works with re library (out-of-the-box). I have to select it as an answer. Thank you anyways.